# Connecting windows .net to sas server

Tags: .net, sas

I am connecting windows .net application to sas, using the code below, but i am getting an error stating that

> implicit cast is not allowed

at the line where we are making connection to work space by createworkspaceby server method.

can you please help me with this part.

```
SASWorkspaceManager.WorkspaceManager oWorkspaceManager
    = new SASWorkspaceManager.WorkspaceManager();
string xmlInfo = "";

SASWorkspaceManager.ServerDef oServerDef = new SASWorkspaceManager.ServerDef();
oServerDef.MachineDNSName = "server";
oServerDef.Protocol = SASWorkspaceManager.Protocols.ProtocolBridge;
oServerDef.Port = <port>;
oServerDef.BridgeEncryptionAlgorithm = "SASProprietary";
oServerDef.BridgeEncryptionLevel = 
    SASWorkspaceManager.EncryptionLevels.EncryptUserAndPassword;

SAS.Workspace oSASWorkspace = 
    oWorkspaceManager.Workspaces.CreateWorkspaceByServer ("", 
    SASWorkspaceManager.Visibility.VisibilityProcess, oServerDef, "user",
    "pass", out xmlInfo);

oSASWorkspace.LanguageService.Submit(
    "proc means data = sashelp.class;output out=meanout;run;");
OleDbDataAdapter oOleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter
                        ("select * from work.meanout",
    "provider=sas.iomprovider.1; SAS Workspace ID=" + 
    oSASWorkspace.UniqueIdentifier);
DataSet oDS = new DataSet();
oOleDbDataAdapter.Fill(oDS, "sasdata");

oWorkspaceManager.Workspaces.RemoveWorkspaceByUUID(
    oSASWorkspace.UniqueIdentifier);
oSASWorkspace.Close();
```

Comment: This sounds to me like a basic programming issue ("[Casting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105(v=vs.110).aspx)"), not related to "SAS" or anything else.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056381/reading-data-from-a-sas-data-source-in-net - Starting with 9.13, WorkspaceManager is deprecated in favor of ObjectManagerMulti. Also is that <port> meant to be like that?

Answer (score 0):

@blue9man, based on the code the below line must be causing the error

```
oServerDef.Port = <port>;
```

Based on the code, You should replace  with a port no.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569672/creating-a-workspace-session-using-sas-iom-vba) on how to get hold of the port No.